# VBA Code to filter data and transfer to other sheet based on MULTIPLE criteria

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to filter data and transfer it to another sheet, I already seen examples of transferring data but the criteria is just 1. I need to set 5 criteria and to filter 5 different fields. There is something wrong with my syntax whenever i try to put **xlAutoFilterOperator= xlAnd** , please help me to correct it.

```
Sub FilterTransfer()

Dim sh As Worksheet, ws As Worksheet
Dim var As Variant
Dim var1 As Variant
Dim var2 As Variant
Dim var3 As Variant
Dim var4 As Variant
Dim var5 As Variant
Dim var6 As Variant
Dim sub1 As Variant
Dim sub2 As Variant
Dim sub3 As Variant
Dim sub4 As Variant
Dim acc1 As Variant
Dim acc2 As Variant
Dim acc3 As Variant
Dim acc4 As Variant

var = "F"
var1 = "Kaz"
var2 = "COS - Jessie"
var3 = "INM - Jessie"
var4 = "Jimmy"
var5 = "Belinda"
var6 = "Critical"
sub1 = "Yes"
sub2 = "No"
sub3 = "With Dependency"
sub4 = "TBD"
acc1 = "Yes"
acc2 = "No"
acc3 = "With Dependency"
acc4 = "TBD"


Set sh = Worksheets("Raw Data") 'set the sheet to filter
Set ws = Worksheets("Sheet1") 'set the sheet to paste
ws.Range("AD1", ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp)).ClearContents '<--| clear "paste" sheet columns A:L cells from row 1 down to column A last not empty one

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

With sh '<--| reference your "copy" sheet
    With .Range("AD1", .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp)) '<--| reference its columns A:L cells from row 1 down to column A last not empty cell
        .AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:=var 'filter on referenced range 9th column with 'var'
       .AutoFilter Field:=5, Criteria1:=var6
       .AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:=var1, Criteria2:=var2, xlAutoFilterOperator= xlAnd, Criteria3:=var3, Criteria4:=var4, Criteria5:=var5
        .AutoFilter Field:=16, Criteria1:=sub1, Criteria2:=sub2, xlAutoFilterOperator= xlAnd, Criteria3:=sub3, Criteria4:=sub4
       .AutoFilter Field:=21, Criteria1:=acc1, Criteria2:=acc2, xlAutoFilterOperator= xlAnd, Criteria3:=acc3, Criteria4:=acc4



        If Application.WorksheetFunction.Subtotal(103, .Cells) > 1 Then .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1) '<--| if any cell filtered other than headers (which get always filtered) then copy filtered values to "paste" sheet
    End With
    .AutoFilterMode = False
End With

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: autofilter is not your solution.  You need to use an advanced filter with "extract to".

Comment: can you please give me some examples on how to use advanced filter with extract to? thank you

Comment: @JohnnyD, you can do it with AutoFilter, see my answer

Comment: Off the question topic, but you should name your variables something sensible. When they're all `varX` or `a, b, c` it'll bite you when you come back to this code in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do with `AutoFilter` exploiting its `xlFilterValues` parameter and passing an array of filter values, as follows:

```
Sub FilterTransfer()

    Dim sh As Worksheet, ws As Worksheet
    Dim var As Variant, var6 As Variant
    Dim filters1 As Variant, filters2 As Variant

    var = "F"
    var6 = "Critical"
    filters1 = Array("F", "Kaz", "COS - Jessie", "INM - Jessie", "Jimmy")
    filters2 = Array("Yes", "No", "With Dependency", "TBD")



    Set sh = Worksheets("Raw Data") 'set the sheet to filter
    Set ws = Worksheets("Sheet01") 'set the sheet to paste
    ws.Range("AD1", ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp)).ClearContents '<--| clear "paste" sheet columns A:L cells from row 1 down to column A last not empty one

'    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    With sh '<--| reference your "copy" sheet
        With .Range("AD1", .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp)) '<--| reference its columns A:L cells from row 1 down to column A last not empty cell
            .AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:=var 'filter on referenced range 9th column with 'var'
            .AutoFilter Field:=5, Criteria1:=var6
            .AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:=filters1, Operator:=xlFilterValues
            .AutoFilter Field:=16, Criteria1:=filters2, Operator:=xlFilterValues
            .AutoFilter Field:=21, Criteria1:=filters2, Operator:=xlFilterValues

            If Application.WorksheetFunction.Subtotal(103, .Cells) > 1 Then .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1) '<--| if any cell filtered other than headers (which get always filtered) then copy filtered values to "paste" sheet
        End With
        .AutoFilterMode = False
    End With

'    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

should you want to Move" data, just change this snippet:

```
        If Application.WorksheetFunction.Subtotal(103, .Cells) > 1 Then
            .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1) '<--| if any cell filtered other than headers (which get always filtered) then copy filtered values to "paste" sheet
            .Resize(.Rows.Count - 1).Offset(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete '
        End If
```

Comment: Nice and Fast ! I have not seen the use of `AutoFilter` with having `<--|` in the comments section for a year, since user @user3598756 has disappeared

Comment: @ShaiRado, thank you. While ...well, I just copied and modified the OP's code with those comments!

Comment: Is it possible to transfer the data not just paste it to another sheet but completely move it? I want to see an output which the "RAW DATA" sheet will completely move the filtered data to "Sheet01". Thanks

Comment: @PatriciaKarenPecadizo see code at the end of edited answer